# How to get multiple entities from a Hibernate SQL join

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, orm

I have 4 table:

`Orders(orderID, orderDate, orderItem (OneToMany))`

`OrderItem(id, order(manyToOne), book (manyToOne), quantity)`

`Book (id, title, cost)`

`User(id, username, password)`

Here is my query in `SQL`:

```
String sql = "SELECT orders.id, book.title, orderitem.quantity
    FROM orderitem INNER JOIN book ON book.id = orderitem.book_id INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = orderitem.orders_id WHERE user_id = 1;
```

`(user_id is the foreign key of User in Orders table)`

`(orders_id is the foreign key of Orders in OrderItem table)`

```
List<OrderItem> orderBookInfo = (List<OrderItem>) session.createSQLQuery(sql); // returns List<Object[]> why?!
```

This query result comes from joining of 3 tables (`Book`, `Order`, `OderItem`)

And this is the result in table:

[image]

Question is how can i assign each result's column to it's corresponding properties?

For example:

```
orderBookInfo.order.id = (first location of orderBookInfo)

orderBookInfo.book.title = (second location of orderBookInfo)
```

Comment: You must use hibernate criteria and I can not see orderitem quantity property.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli `quantity ` is the same as `QTY` , i correct it.

Comment: Your table has no column with named by quantity

Comment: You did not understood me.Your OrderItem table has no column named by quantity.But in your select statement your wrote orderitem.quantity

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli Sorry, i correct it.I forgot it.

Comment: Please correct your question. Where is user_id?

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli `user_id` is the foreign key of `User` in `Orders` table.

Comment: Please,explain your question clearly. You did not wrote about user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute an Entity query instead. Assuming you already mapped the entities properly, this is how the HQL query would look like:

```
SELECT o
FROM orderitem oi
JOIN FETCH oi.book
JOIN FETCH oi.orders 
JOIN FETCH oi.user u 
WHERE u.id = 1;
```